# How to search filter array item inside the array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, use-state

My problem is that I want to find the category of the every title movie that I want to search. For example

> searchInput  = Action
>
> outputShown = [Transformer,Dinosaur, Godzilla]

Since I have category that listed as you see below:

```
    const category = ['Comedy','Classic','Drama','Romance','Science- 
     Fiction','Adult','Sex','Kids','Animation','Cartoon','Action','Storyline','Tragic']
```

I wanted this TitleItems to have match to my searchinput even if they have different type of category.

```
    const TitleItems =  {
            imgPath:'', name:'The Office',type:['Comedy','Classic','Romance'],views:"5666",rate:"4.1"
        },
        {
            imgPath:'', name:'Ready Player One',type:['Science-Fiction','Romance','Drama'],views:"7776",rate:"4.2"
        },
        {
            imgPath:'', name:'Interstellar',type:['Science-Fiction','Drama','Romance','Tragic'],views:"10505",rate:"4.5"
        },
        {
            imgPath:'', name:'Transformer',type:['Science-Fiction','Action','Classic','Comedy'],views:"20015",rate:"4.3"
        },
        {
            imgPath:'', name:'Jack N The Giant',type:['Science-Fiction','Action','Adult','Comedy'],views:"12234",rate:"4.2"
        }
```

As you see this is the searchinput, my only problem here is item.type, Since it have an array
I cannot do it as `item.type.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())`, but I can do it as `item.type[0].toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())` because it cannot include a array but what I really wanna do it must be search in that array of every item type of the title. So I wonder how's that gonna work? Anyone idea? I don't know if I ask the right question. Please edit it for me if it's a terrible question.

```
    const [search,setsearch] = useState("");

    const ListItems = items.filter((item,index) => {
        return (
            item.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
            item.views.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
            item.rate.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) || 
            item.type.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
        )   
    }).map((item,index) => {
        return(
            <div>
                <h1 key={index}> 
                    {item.name}, {item.type} {item.views} {item.rate} 
                </h1>

            </div>

        )
    })
```

And here is the body to show the output

```
    <input type="text" name='search' placeholder='Search...' value={search} onChange={e => setsearch(e.target.value)} />
     {ListItems}
```

Comment: You can use regular expressions. 
(new RegExp( item.type.join( "|" ), "i")).test(search.toLowerCase())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend that condition using [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) (The some() method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function).

```
item.type.some(category => category.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()))
```

In your filter condition, update it as below

```
const [search,setsearch] = useState("");

const ListItems = items.filter((item,index) => {
    return (
        item.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
        item.views.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
        item.rate.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) || 
        item.type.some(category => category.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()))
    )   
}).map((item,index) => {
    return(
        <div>
            <h1 key={index}> 
                {item.name}, {item.type} {item.views} {item.rate} 
            </h1>

        </div>

    )
})
```

Comment: Can I do item.type.some(item.type => item.type.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())) ? just curious

Comment: That is also fine. because item inside callback of some is in another scope. But it reduces the readability of your code. It should be like this then`item.type.some(item => item.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()))`

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through your list and in that list, add any category that includes that filter text.

You will use two array methods, `forEach`  and `some`.

Simple explanation for your question:

```
// example from your scenario
const TitleItems: { id: number, list: string[] }[] = [
    {
        id: 12,
        list: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
    }
]

// the accumulator function that shall be taking in the values that have passed our given test
let accumulator: any[] = []

// first loop through all the items by forEach
TitleItems.forEach((item) => {

// then use a comparison using some, some will return true when any element in it matches the query you put
// the query should be your search string
if (item.list.some(item => item === '12')) {
    accumulator.push(item)
}
})
```

In the end, your accumulator array will have the values that have passed that condition....

For a very advanced solution that I'd not recommend for a beginner is to use the array reduce function to sort out that case.

Read more about the *some* method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: this sounds complicated..I don't understand.

Comment: but still I will used this thanks.